# What is "Theodical" disappointment?

Tags: meaning

A recent [Wired article](http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/11/mf_bitcoin/4/) had the following sentence:  "... beneath the paranoia and infighting lurked something more vulnerable, an almost **theodical** disappointment."

I've never encountered this word, and I haven't found it in any online dictionaries either.  I'd guess it shares a root with Theology, but I can't guess at the exact meaning.

--Edit--

Even after reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy), the meaning of this sentence is not clear.  What makes  disappointment "theodical" when the subject is not God?

Comment: First Google hit on the word: http://www.js.emory.edu/BLUMENTHAL/Theodicy.html .

Comment: That article starts off using the word as if the reader knows what it means: "Theodicy is grounded in cognitive dissonance."

Comment: General reference. With "Google Instant", just typing **theodi** puts up *theodicy* as the word you're probably looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Theodical* is of or relating to *theodicy*, for which Wordnik aggregates [several definitions](http://www.wordnik.com/words/theodicy). The most pertinent is probably this one:

> : an area of philosophy that treats of the nature and government of God

In the context of the article, Satoshi Nakamoto was the god of the bitcoining world; and his absence in the face of the implosion of the world he had created led the bitcoiners to question their god's 'goodness' and very existence.

To paraphrase the article:

> Why had their god created this world only to abandon it?

Answer (score 0):

In actual technical merit word "Theodical" doesnt exist in dictionary either Oxford or Webster and therefore its use is questionable in a formal context. The correct adjective would have been "Theodidact disappointment" because that is the correct adjective for theodicy.

And in the context of its supposed meaning, it merely states disappointment in the ways of God.